# Img align bottom to the bottom of a div

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is align my logo with the bottom of the header div which I have placed it in. I have the header split into 2 sections header left and header right I only need the site logo displayed on the left side of the header so it only needs to be a max of 350px with a 55px left margin. i can get it aligned in the center easily but Idk what is going wrong and why I can not get it to align to the bottom of the header. I tried some other steps from the forums here and nothing worked.

```css
}
header {
 background-color: #6699cc;
    overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 background: no-repeat center center cover;
 display: block;
 border: 0px;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px 20px 20px;
}
#header-left { 
 width: 50%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div id="header-left">
  <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Tech World Today" align="bottom"/>
 </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Because you haven't specified `height` on `#header-left`.

Comment: set the header `position: relative;` and make the logo `position:absolute; bottom: 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this to your css:**

```
img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

**See fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/ocme3jqb/

> PS: I added a set height width to your header to show you the effect.

Comment: Actually, it was suppose to have a set height I believe to begin with. Thank you for your help I applied the same options to two other divs within the same element and it fixed my issue entirely and I learned a lot about positioning divs in the process. Thank you again!

Comment: happy to help! @GregShepherd